# how to add flag sequence number in unique and duplicate value using sql

Tags: sql, row-number, dbeaver

i have table A with 2 columns was filled: Date, product. and column count still empty

my expectation, if same product have in same date then count 1.

i want the flag in count as sequence.
[image]

i got stuck, thanks before

Comment: This is a great chance for your today's good deed: Get rid of SQL key words as column name. "Date" is really no good column name. Not only because it's a keyword, but also it doesn't tell you which date it is. The date a product has been sold, the date a product has been manufactured, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `DENSE_RANK()` here:

```sql
SELECT date, product, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date, product) count
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date, product;
```

Comment: many thanks @Tim Biegeleisen. thats script is work